# Any better approach for layout design?

Tags: android, layout

just wondering if anyone else has a better suggestion that what I'm coming up with.

The issue is to do with a TabLayout, 5 Tabs all using a single Activity.  Each Tab layout contains quite a few fields so the main parent on each tab is a ScrollView.

What I currently have is a 'Save' & 'Cancel' button sitting outside the scrollviews so theyre always visible and there for the user regardless which tab they're on.  The problem is that since I'm using Tabs and always have these buttons visible when they are editing and the IME is displayed, they'res barely any of the form visible.

So I think the best thing for me to do is to probably show the buttons at the end of each scrollview.  What I don't like about this is as I have 5 tabs, it will mean I have to declare 5 sets of the buttons, and of course define them and bind them in the Activity.. which seems rather messy and inefficient.

So if anyone has any better ideas I sure would love to hear them :-)

Thanks

Rgds,

Dave[image]

Comment: it'd help if you posted a pic of the screen

Comment: Ok will do, but the layout issue must be quite a common problem when the IME is present as that takes up 50% of the screen, then the tabs about 10% and my buttons another 10%, so theres not much of the screen left to show the important bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the options you got is

- Try to put a title bar, and move the save and cancel buttons there (Small image buttons).
- Save can be moved to the menu too (not recommended).
- Auto Save functionality can also help, depends on how useful is it to you.
- Try to use custom images for tabs, and make it take less space.
- else, remove the save and cancel buttons, after the user makes any modifications, and presses back, prompt him to save the unsaved changes.

Comment: Yes I think perhaps a combination of these would be useful.. I wonder if shrinking/hiding the tab widget would work only when the IME is visible.  I don't really want to adjust the default sizes of the tabs as they are easy to press at that size... they're just not so useful in the middle of entering data

Answer (score 1):

You could make it that when you're in tab X, the tab button for tab X now becomes X(save), so if they click again on the tab button in the same tab, it saves.  That saves you five buttons, potentially...

Answer (score 1):

Define programmatically the buttons inside a LinearLayout and add them to each ScrollView with addView. The code of the buttons should check in what tab are we at that moment, and act accordingly.

Then you'll have the same two buttons arranged in the same way in all your ScrollViews.

Or, if you dislike doing it programmatically, do a layout for the buttons and use View.inflate of that layout, and add them via addView to the ScrollView.